# Apache Unable to load mod plugin

Tags: apache

I'm trying to integrate Websphere and Apache httpd model, while trying to verify the syntax I'm getting below error. The reason of the failure is required model is (/mod_was_ap22_http.so) is not available in my machine, can you please some help from where i can download this model?

```
[root@packer-123 bin]# ./apachectl -t
httpd: Syntax error on line 511 of /opt/app/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /opt/app/apache/plugin85/bin/64bits/mod_was_ap22_http.so into server: /opt/app/apache/plugin85/bin/64bits/mod_was_ap22_http.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some information on the official IBM website, it shows the error you are having, it says that if you are using Apache with 32-bit addressing support and you used the 64-bit CD you will get the problem you describe.
There is more information in case you want to review it
This is the link

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tins_manualWebApache22.html

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for the quick response, but where i can get mod file mod_was_ap24_http.so file,